# How do you create a timer in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer

I'm currently programming a brick-breaker clone using the Pyglet library and I would like to make a timer that counts up to 20 seconds for the game's 'bonuses'(i.e. longer paddle, faster paddle movement, a larger ball). I've been digging the internet as hard as I can but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: are you looking for `time.sleep`? I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: "Timer" has a specific meaning wrt computer code. Did you mean "timed counter display"?

Comment: I don't know Pyglet, but this may be helpful: [Calling functions periodically](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/calling_functions_periodically.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import threading

bonuses_count = 0

def count_bonuses():
    global bonuses_count
    # paddle = count(paddle) # something your logic part here
    bonuses_count += 20
    print "counting bonuses :- ", (bonuses_count) 
    t = threading.Timer(20.0, count_bonuses).start()

t = threading.Timer(20.0, count_bonuses)
t.start()
```

Well i don't know your logic of counting bonuses but i think you can acheive 20 seconds timer by creating a **thread** which will executing after every 20 seconds.

Here i have created function **count_bonuses** that will contain your game logic and get executed after every 20 seconds.

You can create your own **stopflag** if you want to stop this thread or create an **KeyboardInterrupt** to stop the thread with keyboard intruption based on your gamming logic.

```
counting bonuses :-  20
counting bonuses :-  40
counting bonuses :-  60
counting bonuses :-  80
```

Comment: @Don Abril My bad, I have edited my answer. If you feel that the answer was right or it was helpful please accept the answer or give it an upvote so that it would be helpful for me and others who have  or will face similar problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import mx.DateTime as mt
import time
def settime():
    st=mt.now()
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1)
        tt=mt.now()
        if (int((tt-st).seconds)==20):
            print 'level up'
            st=mt.now()
        elif (int((tt-st).seconds)>20):
            print 'logic error'
        else:
            print int((tt-st).seconds)
```