# is it possible to codein that after every 2 hours this script restarts?

Tags: python, proxy

I currently have this script

```
import os
import time


os.system("killall -9 chromium-browser");


from config import *
with open(PROXIES_FILE) as f: proxies=f.read().split('\n')
proxies=[proxy.strip() for proxy in proxies if proxy.strip()]
for i in range(NUM):
    if len(proxies)<=i: break
    os.system('nohup chromium-browser --proxy-server="http://{proxy}" --disable-popup-blocking -new-window --user-data-dir=~/tmp/f{i} {url}&'.format(url=URL, i=i, proxy=proxies[i]))
    time.sleep(5)
print('%s browsers opened successfully!'%(i+1))
```

is it possible to script in that it will restart itself after every 2 hours?

Comment: Why not just count the number of times you time.sleep(5), and after 14,400 passes, terminate?

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942801/how-do-you-create-a-timer-in-python-2-7/26943075#26943075 and one more solution could be using screen https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the whole code in a function and call that function every 2 hours, and run this script in background by converting it into a daemon. Also to make sure the function executes after almost exactly 2 hours you need to return the total number of seconds the function went to sleep(to get the total number of seconds spent in the function you can add the line `t = time.time()` at the start of the function and then in the end return `time.time() - t`).

```
import os
import time
from config import *

def func():

    os.system("killall -9 chromium-browser");
    with open(PROXIES_FILE) as f: proxies=f.read().split('\n')
    proxies=[proxy.strip() for proxy in proxies if proxy.strip()]
    seconds_slept = 0
    for i in range(NUM):
        if len(proxies)<=i: break
        os.system('nohup chromium-browser --proxy-server="http://{proxy}" --disable-popup-blocking -new-window --user-data-dir=~/tmp/f{i} {url}&'.format(url=URL, i=i, proxy=proxies[i]))
        time.sleep(5)
        seconds_slept += 5
    print('%s browsers opened successfully!'%(i+1))
    return seconds_slept

while True:
    time.sleep(2*60*60 - func())
```

Now you can run this script as daemon using the solutions from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706394/846892).

Answer (score 1):

if you are under linux just use [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

"Cron is a system daemon used to execute desired tasks (in the background) at designated times. "

it's by far the most common tool for this